# What is the Wildcard for expression engine?

Tags: ifelse

I am trying to use the wildcard for my {if} statement. Where I could have P12,P24,P36,48, etc.

```
{if segment_4 !="" && segment_4 !="P*"}
```

But The wildcard is not working for me, does the queries need to be turned on or something?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no wildcards in EE. You're probably looking for something like [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee), where you can use regular expression matching, or [Mo Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables), which gives you `{if paginated}`, which could help here.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Segment Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/segment-search) which is another free addon and allows more control of segment searching. This should work:

```
{exp:segment_search keyword="/P\d+/" segments="4" regex="yes"}
```